# How to remove blanks from a select box in PHP?

Tags: php, select

I have a select box where I have a blank row in my SQL. What the best way not to display this?

Here is the code for the segment that I have.

I have tried `array_filter` with no luck!

```
<label for="SS">Seat Style:  </label>
    <select id="SS">
    <option>----</option>
    <?
    foreach ($liftsecond as $lift){
echo '<option>'.$lift["Seat Style"].'</option>';

}
?>
</select><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly easy. Just do an `if` statement checking for empty:

```
<label for="SS">Seat Style:  </label>
<select id="SS">
    <option>----</option>
    <?php
      // If the value runs, but the value is NULL,
      // try using array_filter() to remove the null
      $liftsecond = array_filter($liftsecond);
      foreach ($liftsecond as $lift) {
        // If null is not removed, try using this if statement
        // (you need to know if the null is "NULL" or "null")
        // This checks both empty and null
        // if(!empty($lift["Seat Style"]) && $lift["Seat Style"] != 'null')
        if(!empty($lift["Seat Style"])) {
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $lift["Seat Style"]; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
      }
    ?>
</select><br>
```

Comment: easier to select the non blank rows in the first place `WHERE  XX !='' `

Comment: @zlen: I think you mean Dagon. There's tab completion of names here in comments btw - a very cool hidden feature. Just type the '@' a letter or two, then hit the Tab key.

Comment: in this select box there is one option that is not empty and one that is. I want to still be able to display 1 option.

Comment: Yeah, the `if(!empty($lift["Seat Style"]))` will only display if the `$lift["Seat Style"]` value is not empty.

Comment: i have just uploaded it to a temp site to try and show you what i mean. if you could look at it i would be very grateful [link](http://www.simmondsp.net/form.php) If you click the top option (simplicity plus) then the form will load. if you go down to seat style you will see where my problem is.

Comment: Howdy! I see what you are saying, are you saying the code above does not work? It should for that instance.

Comment: no that code hasn't worked because there is 1 value in there. the second value that is in the sql is a null value. I want to try and hide the null values in the dropdown list

Comment: Try `array_filter()` if the value is truely `null`, It should filter it out.